# How did we get the data we use in spectroscopy?

Tags: spectroscopy

When we look at light coming from distant stars and observe which wavelengths have been filtered out by matter the light has passed through, how did we collect that data on which kinds of molecules absorb or reflect which wavelengths of light?

Was it just experimentally collected?

If so, does our current model of atomic/molecular physics even allow us to predict which wavelengths of light a molecule will block simply based on its structure?

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, we collected that data experimentally here on Earth, at first using plasma lamps and actual glass prisms to crudely replicate the surface of stars, and later on using more sophisticated equipment to the point that we have very precise spectra of just about every molecule or atom found in nature.

To answer your second question, not yet! For years the only thing we could experimentally predict the spectrum of was hydrogen. It took computers to experimentally predict other elements, and even today it takes a supercomputer days to be able to calculate from first principles the (very rough) spectrum of even the most simple molecules.

So yes, its all experimental. For now.